# React isn't finding a module even though I set the path correctly

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, so I apologize for the noobness of this question.

I just created a new React application, and I've been playing around with the folder structure. Below is my current folder structure:

```
react-app
  |_ src
    |_ assets
      |_ images
        |_ logo
          |_ logo.svg
    |_ components
      |_ App
        |_ App.js
    index.js
```

In /react-app/src/components/App/App.js, I need to import logo.svg, which is located in /react-app/src/assets/images/logo/logo.svg.

In App.js, I have this line to import the logo:

```
import logo from '../assets/images/logo/logo.svg';
```

I get the following error:

```
./src/components/App/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../assets/images/logo/logo.svg'
```

What I tried:

- changing it to './assets/images/logo/logo.svg'
- changing it to '/assets/images/logo/logo.svg'
- changing it to '/src/assets/images/logo/logo.svg'
- changing it to '.../assets/images/logo/logo.svg'
- changing it to '..../assets/images/logo/logo.svg'
- changing it to '...../assets/images/logo/logo.svg'

I put the logo.svg inside src/components/App and it loaded just fine with './logo.svg'

I then put the logo.svg inside src/components, and was able to load it with '../logo.svg'

I put it in src, and I get the error again when using '.../logo.svg'

Conclusion: I can't import logo.svg when it's more than two directories above the component that is trying to import it.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the import path to `../../assets/images/logo/logo.svg`.

Each `../` denotes going up 1 directory.

So it goes like

1. `../`, go up to `components` directory
2. `../`, go up again to `src` directory
3. `assets/`, go into the `assets` directory
4. `logo/`, go into the `logo` directory inside `assets`
5. `logo.svg`, finally get the file

Comment: Thank for this problem! You explain clear.